# Integration issue with Nintegrate over finite bounds

Tags: numerical-integration

I have an issue :

```
NIntegrate[x^2 *Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

gives out 
0.443113

But :

```
NIntegrate[x^2 *Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, 6857}]
```

gives an error:

> NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option.

and a zero as a result

However:

NIntegrate[x^2 *Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, 6855}]

gives the correct answer of 0.443113.

What is the difference of integrating over 6855 or 6857 ?
(I am not really aware of the insides of mathematica and how it calculates the integrals numerically).

Addition to my question - how to access the properties of integration and play with the parameters.

Thank you a lot for your help :)

Comment: Note that `NIntegrate`'s message "izero" pretty much tells you how to get a better result. As for "how to access the properties of integration and play with the parameters." -- all of these are answered in [the advanced `NIntegrate` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html).

Comment: What version have you observed this with? I cannot reproduce your results and message in 11.3: for both sets of limits I get 0.443113 .

Comment: @AntonAntonov One guess is that in V11.3, machine underflow (`General::munfl`) is used as a signal for recursive subdivision.  Certainly a `Trace[]` indicates that the underflow message is suppressed.

Comment: @AntonAntonov On 11.3, I had to go a little higher than 6857 to induce the problem, but I didn't think it was important enough to highlight in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`x^2*Exp[-x^2]` is effectively 0 at most points in your interval.

```
Reduce[x^2*Exp[-x^2] >= $MinMachineNumber]
(* -26.7389 <= x <= -1.49167*10^-154 || 1.49167*10^-154 <= x <= 26.7389 *)
```

`NIntegrate` works by sampling the function. If it never finds a nonzero sample, you'll see the error. But the message gives you the advice to fix the problem.

```
NIntegrate[x^2*Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, 10000}, MinRecursion -> 5]
(* 0.443113 *)
```